# Generate subsets of two elements of parameters

Tags: python, list

I am a brand new to python and currently I am working on generating subsets in the list with function. Here is the sample I need to get back.

Eg.

- String: `AECG`
- Subsets: `['AE', 'AC', 'AG', 'EC', 'EG', 'CG']`

I was thinking to put the string into an empty list and then play around the list , but it doesn't work . Can you help please~

```
result=[]
s="AECG"

for i in s:
    result.append(i)
    for j in range (0,len(result)-1):
        for x in range (1,len(result)):
            subsets=result.append(j,x)
    print(subsets)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations('AECG', 2))
[('A', 'E'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('E', 'C'), ('E', 'G'), ('C', 'G')]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations('AECG', 2)] # tuples -> strings
['AE', 'AC', 'AG', 'EC', 'EG', 'CG']
```

---

**UPDATE** Using `map`, and a bound method `''.join`:

```
>>> list(map("".join, itertools.combinations('AECG', 2)))
['AE', 'AC', 'AG', 'EC', 'EG', 'CG']
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness here is the solution without itertools

```
subsets=[]
s="AECG"

for i in range (len(s)):
    for j in range (i+1, len(s)):
          subsets.append(s[i]+s[j]) # append modifies the list
print(subsets)
```

Comment: I was thinking about using two for loops , but I did not know how to apply it appropriately.  Thank you, It  makes more sense now